# Entity Framework 6, Database First, MVC5 import view

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MS Sql, database has 30 views; I can import all except this one:

```
SELECT        ClinicId, Cold, COUNT(Cold) AS Patients, CEILING(CAST(COUNT(Cold) AS decimal) /  (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1
         FROM            dbo.vw_Patients AS vw
         WHERE        (ClinicId = dbo.vw_patients.ClinicId)) * 100) AS Percentage
FROM         dbo.vw_Patients
WHERE        (ClinicId IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY Cold, ClinicId
```

Any idea why I can't import it; it works with linq-to-sql.

Comment: Probably because there isn't any non-nullable column and EF cannot infere the key? Open your edmx file with an Xml editor and you should be able to find this view commented out along with the details about what went wrong.

Comment: You are correct Pawel, the error is: 
does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred.  Will try to figure out how to fix it.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Add a column that can be used as a key or - if you already have columns that you know that in fact never have null values and can be used to identify a row (i.e. no duplicates) modify your edmx manually by changing nullability for this column and making them keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your views does not have any non-nullable column and, as a result, EF designer cannot infer key columns. You may need to add a column you would use to identify rows or, if you already have columns that you know that in fact can never have null values and can be used to identify a row (i.e. no two rows will have the same combination of values), modify your edmx manually by changing nullability for these columns and making them keys

In general in cases like this you can open your edmx file with an Xml editor and you should be able to find the item that was excluded (written as a comment) along with the details about why it was excluded.